# Bootstrap-Select dropdown skips 1 when moving manually with down arrow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

Live search works as intended, but when I hit the down arrow key to move manually down the results, it skips 1 for every keystroke. Goes to 1,3,5,7 , etc. skipping 2,4,6, and so on.

This is a rails app, 
Ive setup bootstrap-select-rails in gemfile and Im loading at the head if my layout:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
```

at the bottom of my layout :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
 });
 </script>
```

How can I solve this? Thanks!

```
 <select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit" data-live-search="true" title="Zona" onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
            <option value="">España, Alava</option>
            <option value="">España, Albacete</option>
            <option value="">España, Alicante</option>
            <option value="">España, Almeria</option>
            <option value="">España, Asturias</option>
            <option value="">España, Avila</option>
            <option value="">España, Badajoz</option>
            <option value="">España, Barcelona, Ciutat Vella</option>
            <option value="">España, Barcelona, Eixample</option>
            <option value="">España, Barcelona, Sants Montjuic</option>
            <option value="">España, Barcelona, Les Corts</option>
 </select>
```

[image: image1]

Comment: Can anyone suggest areas to look into?

Comment: It doesn't look ruby-on-rails or twitter problem, just a boostrap selectpicker one. I have the same problem with php generated selects and even a pure HTML select with just selectpicker as the class.

Answer (score 3):

Ok this may gonna sound stupid, but it just worked for me.
Are you using both bootstrap-select.js and bootstrap-select.min.js?

I had both, but the correct functionality was restored after i excluded the .min.js part. The error seems to be in that file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation, but my issue was that I've added the library two times in my HTML  element. After removing one of them, it's working now as expected.